# jquery addclass id not working on list

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please check my code,

**CSS**

```
.ulData li.sel {
    background:#fff !important;
    font-size:0.8em;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

**JS**

```
function switchTab(typ){
    $(".ulData li").removeClass("sel");
    $("#"+typ).addClass("sel");
    $("."+ typ +"Options").addClass("sel");
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="ulData">
  //For Loop li
  <li title="${option.id}" id="${option.key}"><span>aaaa</span></li>
</ul>
```

If I click on a button, I call switchTab function. In there I am adding the 'sel' class.
If I am adding like,

```
$("li#"+typ).addClass("sel");
```

Then working in Firefox but non of the IE versions. please help how to apply the CSS for all the browser compatibilities.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `typ` and where does it come from? Can you please post all relevant code related to it, i.e. where is `switchTab` being called etc.

Comment: Could you share the code where `switchTab` is being called?

Comment: I briefly explained because its a very large code and the function is calling from the same JSP File and I am sure about it. I also tried keeping an alert like alert($("#"+typ).hasClass("sel"));. I got 'true'.

Comment: please check the sample in fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/leobeckons/XyyWf/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/XyyWf/1/ working fine for me in IE. What exactly is the issue you are experiencing there?

Comment: seems, some problem with my coding, let me check once. Thanks buddy

Comment: Damn, found the mistake. Using the same ID in another div layer. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `id` has dots, you have to escape them
(I know they may be template engine ids, but just in case)

`$("#${option.key}")` will not work
`$("#${option\\.key}")` will work

So, to ensure dot-escping do:

```
function switchTab(typ){
  typ = typ.replace(/\./g, "\\\\.");
  //... Your normal code
}
```

**EDIT** You're missing the `$(document).ready()` when calling to `switchTab()`. You should have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    switchTab('companySection');
});
```

I've edited your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XyyWf/2/

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply, my typ will not be option.key, It's the JSP rendering part. my typ will be simple name like 'companySection'.